# Create all possible character combinations of any size

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to create all possible character combinations of a given word.  For example, “laptop” will include the following possible combinations:

```
l
la
lap
lapt
lapto
laptop
lp
lpa
lpat
lpato
lpatop
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import sys

def parse_args(argv):
    """parsing argument"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-input', dest='input', type = str,
                         required = True,
                         help = "please provide string")
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return args


def get_patt(patt, patt_index, new_pat):
    print new_pat
    for i in range(patt_index, len(patt), 1):
        new_pat = new_pat + patt[i]
        print new_pat
def main(args):
    f_pat = ""
    input = args.input
    for k in range(0, len(input), 1):
        for i in range(0, len(input), 1):
            f_pat =  input[i]
            for j in range(i+1, len(input), 1):
                f_pat = f_pat + input[j]
                get_patt(input, j+1, f_pat)
        input = args.input[k:] + args.input[:k]
        print "Input String", input

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args =parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    main(args)
```

Comment: What's with the random `print "Input String", input` that is interleaving with the actual output ?

Comment: I am trying to rotate string  but it is not working with all combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Improvements

1. Use either `argparse` or `sys.argv` because this feels just wierd,
   and kind of surprised it worked at all. I'd recommend sticking with `argparse`
2. Secondly, be sure to check out the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module from python, because what you are looking for are basicly permutations of a word.

---

## New code

```
import argparse
from itertools import permutations


def main(string):
    for idx in range(1, len(string)+1):
        print(list(''.join(p) for p in permutations(string, idx)))


def parse_args():
    """parsing argument"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-input', dest='input', type = str,
                         required = True,
                         help = "please provide string")
    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    main(args.input)
```

Comment: The parameters should not be passed with spaces around `=`. For eg. `required = True` should instead be `required=True` :)

Comment: True, but OP should rather look at the `parse_args` from Mathias :)

Answer (score 2):

Your arguments parsing is a bit off.

If you remove the `-` in front of the name of the argument, `argparse` will consider it a required parameter and not an optional one, so you won't have to specify `required=True`.

Besides, removing it will make the help look cleaner as regard to the fact that the parameter is required:

```
$ python2 combinations.py -h
usage: combinations.py [-h] input

positional arguments:
  input       please provide string

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

You could also return the word from your `parse_args` function so the `main` is agnostic of how you provide your input.

Lastly, a parser's `parse_args` method, if called without arguments, will automatically take `sys.argv[1:]` as the reference. So you don't need to specify it yourself:

```
def parse_args():
    """parsing argument"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input', help='please provide string')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.input


def main(word):
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(parse_args())
```